# How to iterate two elements in a row with ngFor?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, iteration, angular-material2

I have array of strings and I want to place every two of them in a row with ngFor. Here is what I tried:

```
<div class='row wow fadeInUp' *ngFor='let index of myArray;let i = index;'>
     <div class='col-md-6'>
         <md-card>
            <md-card-header>
               <md-card-title>
                 {{index}}
               </md-card-title>
             </md-card-header>
          </md-card>
     </div>
     <div class='col-md-6' *ngIf='i+1 < myArray.length'>
         <md-card>
            <md-card-header>
               <md-card-title>
                 {{myArray[i+1}}
               </md-card-title>
             </md-card-header>
          </md-card>
    </div>
</div>
```

But when I add a new element, it duplicates the previous element and I really don't underestand the reason. How can I add two elements in each row with ngFor?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can skip every other index just by looking for even numbers (0, the first index is even) for *ngIf, and display that items with the next soon be skipped (odd) item:

```
<div class='row wow fadeInUp' *ngFor='let index of myArray; let i = index; let even = even'>
      <span *ngIf="even">
         <div class='col-md-6' >
             <md-card>
                <md-card-header>
                   <md-card-title>
                     {{myArray[i]}}
                   </md-card-title>
                 </md-card-header>
              </md-card>
         </div>
         <div class='col-md-6'>
             <md-card>
                <md-card-header>
                   <md-card-title>
                     {{myArray[i+1]}}
                   </md-card-title>
                 </md-card-header>
              </md-card>
        </div>
       </span>
    </div>
```

[DEMO EXAMPLE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mplrhu?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Note - even is the same as `i % 2 === 0`

Comment: Notice that the parent element is still rendered with no childs.... if it has padding then you'll see some extra "content". Would be nice to not render it at all

Comment: @MareșȘtefan, do you mean like this? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-irdnos?file=app/app.component.html

Comment: @Vega in your case is fine because you are using an ng container. But some people are using a div and give it styles.
Try replacing the bg-container with a div and give it 16px padding. You will end up having extra divs between your rows

Answer (score 3):

`ngFor` exposes `odd` and `even` which can be used to conditionally (using `ngIf`) display some items.

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of array; let even = even">
    <ng-container *ngIf="even">{{ item }}</ng-container>
  </li>
</ul>
```

That said, it's probably better you do this in your code instead of in the template. It's clearer, testable and more perfomant.

```
evenItems = array.filter((_, index) => index % 2 == 0)
```

Then just loop over those.

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of eventItems">
    {{ item }}
  </li>
</ul>
```