# Using index and even in a keyvalue pipe

Tags: angular, angular6, ngfor

I want to iterate over key value pairs from an object and display two items per row. I looked at other examples like this one [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47114498/iterating-two-element-in-a-row-ngfor-angular?rq=1) but I couldn't figure out how to add keyvalue to this.

Here is my code:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of book.bookData.privateData | keyvalue; index as i; let even = even">
    <div fxFlex="100" fxLayout="row" *ngIf="even">
        <div fxFlex="50" fxLayout="column">
            Key: <b>{{book.bookData.privateData[i].key}}</b> and Value: <b>{{book.bookData.privateData[i].value}}</b>
        </div>
        <div fxFlex="50" fxLayout="column">
            Key: <b>{{book.bookData.privateData[i+1].key}}</b> and Value: <b>{{book.bookData.privateData[i+1].value}}</b>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This does not work since there is no `key` and `value` attribute on the `privateData` object, the attributes are assigned to `item`.

Thanks in advance for any help!

EDIT:

The following is a working example of what I'm trying to achieve, but it's clearly not an efficient way:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of bookState.bookData.privateData | keyvalue; index as i; let even = even">
    <div fxFlex="100" fxLayout="row" *ngIf="even">
        <div fxFlex="50">
            <div *ngFor="let deeperItem1 of bookState.bookData.privateData | keyvalue; index as i2">
                <div *ngIf="i2 === i">
                    <b>INDEX {{i2}} and {{i}} </b>Key: <b>{{deeperItem1.key}}</b> and Value: <b>{{deeperItem1.value}}</b>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div fxFlex="50">
            <div *ngFor="let deeperItem2 of bookState.bookData.privateData | keyvalue; index as i3">
                <div *ngIf="(i3-1) === i">
                    <b>INDEX {{i3}} and {{i}} </b>Key: <b>{{deeperItem2.key}}</b> and Value: <b>{{deeperItem2.value}}</b>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

EDIT2:

To specify the question: The problem is not that the keyvalue pipe is not working, the problem is how to efficiently add indexes to these to display x-amount (in my case 2) of items per row.
Sorry for any misunderstanding!

Comment: could you add a schema of what are you looping on? what is in item ?

Comment: What is the `keyvalue` pipe exactly doing or trying to do? Can you share the interface for `pirvateData`?

Comment: privateData contains an arbitrary amount of key value pairs as a JSON response. key and value are both strings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on the structure you are iterating. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41396558/3623608) you can find the following example:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'keyvalue-pipe',
  template: `<span>
    <p>Object</p>
    <div *ngFor="let item of object | keyvalue">
      {{item.key}}:{{item.value}}
    </div>
    <p>Map</p>
    <div *ngFor="let item of map | keyvalue">
      {{item.key}}:{{item.value}}
    </div>
  </span>`
})
export class KeyValuePipeComponent {
  object: {[key: number]: string} = {2: 'foo', 1: 'bar'};
  map = new Map([[2, 'foo'], [1, 'bar']]);
}
```

In your case, if you do not have a key value structure, use the map case like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of book.bookData.privateData | keyvalue; let i=index">
    <div fxFlex="100" fxLayout="row" *ngIf="i%2 === 0">
        <div fxFlex="50" fxLayout="column">
            Key: <b>{{item.key}}</b> and Value: <b>{{item.value}}</b>
        </div>
        <div fxFlex="50" fxLayout="column" *ngIf="(book.bookData.privateData|keyvalue)[i+1]">
            Key: <b>{{(book.bookData.privateData|keyvalue)[i+1].key}}</b> and Value: <b>{{(book.bookData.privateData|keyvalue)[i+1].value}}</b>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: your answer works but does not display two items per row

Comment: @lennertr Post your `array` structure so he could restructure his code

Comment: That's a very tricky one but i finally found a solution. You can apply the pipe within the view by using `(array|pipe)` and access the next element with `(array|pipe)[i+1]`. To make sure that the next element exists using `*ngIf="(book.bookData.privateData|keyvalue)[i+1]"` hopefully helps. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Tommy!! That's what I was looking for :)

Comment: follow up question: can you think of a way to use two way data binding within this?
`<input matInput placeholder="{{item.key}}" [(ngModel)]="item.value">` works only in one way, it doesn't store changes to the book.bookData.privateData object for the corresponding key.

Comment: nevermind that's the solution to that: `[(ngModel)]="loanState.loanData.privateData[item.key]"`

Comment: Sorry for all the follow ups, not sure if I should open a new question for this?
When using two way data binding with ngModel on the second column it throws "Cannot have a pipe in an action expression"
`[(ngModel)]="(book.bookData.privateData|keyvalue)[i+1].value"` is there a workaround?

Comment: Have you tried to use `(ngModelChange)` and `[ngModel]` instead of `[(ngModel)]` syntax as purposes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39643180/3623608)? Otherwise i would suggest to open up a new question.

Answer (score -1):

@lennertr please update your angular version to 6.1.0 to use keyvalue pipe.
because keyvalue is available from version 6.
and please refer below demo.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-keyvalue

Comment: That's not the problem. I'm using an angular version greater than that and the keyvalue pipe works fine. The problem is how to use indexes with the keyvalue pipe to display a specific amount of items per row.